# Guardar valores de um ficheiro de texto num array

Tags: c, array, arquivo

Estou a tentar fazer um código em que preciso de guardar números de um ficheiro de texto num array.
O código que tenho é o seguinte:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  FILE *f;
  int v[10];
  int N=0;
  f=fopen("numeros.txt", "r");
  if(f==NULL)
  {
    printf("Não foi possivel abrir o ficheiro.\n");
    return 0;
  }
  while(fscanf(f, "%d", &v[N]) == 1)
  {
    fscanf(f, "%d", &v[N]);
    printf("%d\n", v[N]);
    N++;
  }
  fclose(f);
  return 0;
}
```

O ficheiro numeros.txt contém:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

O problema é que quando meto fscanf(f, "%d", &v[N]) == 1 ou fscanf(f, "%d", &v[N]) != EOF dentro do while, só me aparecem no ecrã os números 2, 4, 6, 8.

Eu consegui atingir o resultado que queria utilizando !feof(f) dentro do while e funcionou perfeitamente, mas gostava de saber porque é que utilizando o método do fscanf o código não funcionou corretamente.

Tenho visto também em alguns sítios que não é correto utilizar apenas o feof(f) para testar o fim do ficheiro de texto, alguém me consegue explicar o porquê?

Comment: Neste trecho: ` while(fscanf(f, "%d", &v[N]) == 1)
  {
    fscanf(f, "%d", &v[N]);` você faz dois fscanf consecutivos jogando o resultado da leitura na mesma variável. Exclua este fscanf interno ao loop. Deixe apenas: ` while(fscanf(f, "%d", &v[N]) == 1)
  {
    printf("%d\n", v[N]);
    N++;
  }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  FILE *f;
  int v[10];
  int N=0;
  f=fopen("numeros.txt", "r");
  if(f==NULL)
  {
    printf("Não foi possivel abrir o ficheiro.\n");
    return 0;
  }
  while(fscanf(f, "%d", &v[N]) == 1)
  {
    printf("%d\n", v[N]);
    N++;
  }
  fclose(f);
  return 0;
}
```

Repare que, ao inserir o comando fscanf() dentro da condição do while, o mesmo é executado e não apenas verificado se é possível sua execução, e como o mesmo comando aparece dentro do loop o que você fez é ler duas vezes e portanto adicionar de dois em dois os valores do ficheiro no seu vetor, apenas retire o comando fscanf() de dentro do bloco while, afinal ele já executado quando o while testa sua condição e seu problema está resolvido.